# image#.href keeps failing in ie7. why is that?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

this works fine in Chrome, Firefox, etc but not in IE7. I get an error on line 16 that says: "Object doesn't support this action". it seems to fail at this line: image0.href = 'http://www.google.com';

```
if (document.images) {
image0 = new Image;
image1 = new Image;
image2 = new Image;
image3 = new Image;
image4 = new Image;
image5 = new Image;
image6 = new Image;
image7 = new Image;
image8 = new Image;

image0.src = '\/images\/image1.jpg' ;
image0.href = 'http://www.google.com';
image1.src = '\/images\/image2.jpg';
image1.href = 'http:\/\/www.google.com';
image2.src = '\/images\/image3.jpg';
image2.href = 'http:\/\/www.google.com';

image3.src = 'images\/image4.jpg';
image3.href = 'http:\/\/www.google.com';
image4.src = 'images\/image5.jpg';
image4.href ='http:\/\/www.google.com';
image5.src = 'images\/image6.jpg';
image5.href = 'http:\/\/www.google.com';

image6.src = 'images\/image7.jpg';
image6.href ='http:\/\/www.google.com';
image7.src = 'images\/image8.jpg';
image7.href = 'http:\/\/www.google.com';
image8.src = 'images\/image9.jpg';
image8.href = 'http:\/\/www.google.com';

} else {
image0 = '';
image1 = '';
image2 = '';
image3 = '';
image4 = '';
image5 = '';
image6 = '';
image7 = '';
image8 = '';
document.rollimg = '';
document.rollimg2 = '';
document.rollimg3 = '';
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Why are you specifying an href in an image? As far as I know, href isn't an attribute of img.

Answer (score 2):

```
image0 = new Image;
```

Constructors are functions

```
image0 = new Image();
```

Images don't have an `href` property, so this is meaningless:

```
image0.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

And things that are just bad rather than broken.

```
image0 = new Image;
image1 = new Image;
image2 = new Image;
```

Use an array!

```
image0.src = '\/images\/image1.jpg' ;
```

The `/` character has no special meaning in a JS string, it does not need to be escaped.

```
image0 = new Image;
```

Globals are evil. Use scoped variables.

```
var image0 = new Image;
```

… and limit them to the narrowest scope that makes sense for what you need to do.

Comment: ah, thank you so much for the advice! i'm a total javascript newblet as you guys can see haha. got it to work :-)

Comment: I like how your final example completely contradicts your initial advice in the same post.

Comment: It focuses on a specific issue rather then throwing in everything previously mentioned.

Comment: Huh? Your first point instructs to use `()`, then your final point omits it. This is at worst contradictory, and at best confusing.

Comment: And my third point says to use an array. The examples demonstrate how to fix the specific problem described before them. For various reasons, I wasn't going to refactor the entire script (which is needed) myself.

Answer (score 0):

The property `src` is correct. The property `href` does not exist: images are not links. Firefox and/or Chrome may be silently ignoring this, but it's not valid.

See [this thread](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/160764-img-href-object-doesnt-support-action).

Also, there is no reason to escape forward-slashes.

Comment: well, i'm glad IE is cranky and made me rethink my code! thanks! :)

Comment: @steph: No problem! For the benefit of other SO users , please "accept" the answer if you feel that it's the right one.